# How to change color or drawable of Spinner arrow

Tags: android, xml, spinner

Just want to change the color of the `Spinner` arrow (@color or @drawable)

[image]

This is the only code that did something and it make the drawable the entire background of the spinner. (I've tried many other ideas with no luck)

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
...
<item name="android:spinnerStyle">@style/SpinnerColor</item>
</style>

<style name="SpinnerColor" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.Spinner">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp</item>
</style>
```

Here is how I am inflating my `Spinner`

```
mNavigationSpinner = new Spinner(getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext());
mNavigationSpinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);

mNavigationSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
toolbar.addView(mNavigationSpinner);
```

Comment: Are you inflating your Spinner against the ActionBar / Toolbar context, or your activity context? The Toolbar context is themed dark (due to .DarkActionBar) and will have a light-colored ?attr/colorControlNormal tint.

Comment: Hey @alanv, I posted some code about how I am inflating my `Spinner`. (It's in a `Toolbar`). I've set the colorControlNormal to white as well but only the Hamburger buttons changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my fix.

It was a style call in the `Toolbar` that I had forgotten about.

**In toolbar.xml**

**This**

```
app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
```

**Change to this**

```
app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat"
app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
```

Looks identical to [this](http://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/v_2/material_ext_publish/0Bx4BSt6jniD7NTl0UzktM0psQUU/layout_structure_appbar_structure4.png)

Answer (score 1):

okay. you can change the dropdown arrow color using below code

in your styles.xml file just add this attribute  and you good to go.

```
 <item name="android:colorControlNormal">@color/colorAccent</item>
```

for example.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
       <item name="android:colorControlNormal">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
<item name="android:spinnerStyle">@style/SpinnerColor</item>
```

to

```
<item name="android:actionDropDownStyle">@style/SpinnerColor</item>
```

where the

```
<item name="android:background">@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp</item>
```

in SpinnerColor style is a [StateListDrawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList). Items of the StateListDrawable are 9-patch drawables.

Comment: Sorry man, nothing changes... I made an update to my post if you want to peak at how I am inflating the `Spinner`